# Torii session undefined - not injected in ember / firebase app

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, emberfire, torii

In an ember cli project using firebase, I've installed (using `ember install`) emberfire and torii. I have put the following configuration in my `config/environment.js` right after my firebase app url:

```
torii = {
  sessionServiceName: 'session',
}
```

And I've put an adapter into `app/torii-adapters/application.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import ToriiFirebaseAdapter from 'emberfire/torii-adapters/firebase';

export default ToriiFirebaseAdapter.extend({
  firebase: Ember.inject.service()
});
```

However, when I try to get torii's session variable on any route or controller:

```
this.get("session").fetch().catch(function() {});
```

the session is undefined:

```
Error while processing route: app Cannot read property 'fetch' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetch' of undefined
```

I've followed the [firebase docs/examples](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/ember/guide.html#section-authentication) to the best of my knowledge, so I'm not sure what I'm missing. Is another step needed to have torii inject the session variable into all routes and controllers?

---

The versions in my stack are:

```
Ember-CLI: 1.13.7
Firebase (package.json): 2.2.9
EmberFire (package.json): 1.5.0
Torii (package.json): 0.5.1
```

NOTE: I currently have firebase itself working great—all of my models are in sync—so it is not likely the result of a faulty firebase setup. Also, `this.get('session')` returns undefined anywhere in any route or controller in my app.

Comment: are you sure about the line `torii = { sessionServiceName: 'session' }` ? Shouldn't it be `torii: { sessionServiceName: 'session' }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out some sort of caching was preventing the config file from being sourced. After restarting my ember server the session was injected properly into the app.

Comment: Did you restart the server after running `ember install`?

Comment: Yes I did. Specifically though after changing the config to include Torii's session.